# Rails: form css margin

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I have created a form .

In the stylesheets for that form i did this:

```
 .boxPerson{

margin-left: 20px;
}
```

in my view:

```
 <div class="boxPerson">
<p>
<%= f.label :uebung_name, "Name" %> <br />
<%= f.text_field :uebung_name %>

<%= f.label :beschreibung, "Beschreibung" %> <br />
<%= f.text_field :beschreibung %>

<%= f.check_box :_destroy %>
<%= f.label :_destroy, "Remove Question" %>
 </p>
</div>
```

Rails doesnt apply to my css. Whats wrong?

Comment: also, what environment? If this issue is only in production or your environment variables are not default, you need to make sure to pre-compile assets.

Comment: How do you do, i dont understand what to do? Its a normal form for a model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't think this is RUBY related, the cause can be:

1. inheritance in your CSS, some rule negate the margin
2. not correct path to your css
3. typo in/before the CSS rule, this will prevent it from being
   executed

can you check it with firebug?

Answer (score 0):

Does it better, if you fix

```
<div class="boxPerson"<
```

with

```
<div class="boxPerson">
```

?

Because ... if the html wrapper is not well formed, the css couldn't be rendered as well.

Comment: ah sorry its a mistake in my post not in my view